# Jasperreports: How to configure Multi Axis legend?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have a multi axis with two timeSeries as follows:

```
        <multiAxisChart>
            <chart isShowLegend="true" evaluationTime="Report" renderType="svg">
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="555" height="290" uuid="c8ffe397-cf6f-4c8d-8e42-8355c15fd7da"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                **<chartLegend position="Top">
                    <font size="6" isBold="true"/>**
                </chartLegend>
            </chart>
            <multiAxisPlot>
                <plot/>
                <axis>
                    <timeSeriesChart>
                        <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1fb68274-5e87-403a-bf9c-f8fd405f61db"/>
                            <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
```

The highlighted text (** **) does not seem to work. Multiaxis chart legend is still at the botton and with the original font size (10 points):

[image: multiaxis plot]

How do I reduce the legend font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting referred is OK. I don't know why, but Jaspersoft Studio preview does not refresh the change. Nevertheless, in JasperReports server the setting does work correctly.